# How to align an image to the bottom inside a table cell

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment

I created the following document:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}
  \hline
  \parbox[b][1cm]{2cm}{Signature}
  \parbox[b][1cm]{25mm}{\includegraphics[width=25mm]{signature.jpg}}
  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I wanted the signature image to be bottom aligned, but there is a space between it's edge and the bottom border of the cell.

Even though I removed the space at the bottom of the signature picture:

[image]

1. How to shift the picture to the bottom?
2. Is it possible to get rid of the 2-nd `\parbox` --- have the picture placed 1 cm to the right of the word "Signature"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your signature IS bottom aligned. However, you probably want align it according its baseline, not the bottom of the letter y (?). `\raisebox` should solve the problem, e.g. `\raisebox{-3mm}{Box with your signature}`.

Answer (score 4):

Replace

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|X|}
  \hline
  \parbox[b][1cm]{2cm}{Signature}
  \parbox[b][1cm]{25mm}{\includegraphics[width=25mm]{signature.jpg}}
  \\
  \hline
\end{tabularx}
```

by

```
\fbox{Signature\hspace{1cm}%
      \raisebox{-2pt}{\includegraphics[width=25mm]{signature.jpg}}}
```

and adjust the raisebox argument to taste,